# Responsive div layout with relative heights

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to setup a webpage with a fixed header at the top of the page and two grids stacked over each other underneath the header. I want the top grid to occupy 75% of the space underneath the header and the bottom grid should occupy the remaining 25%. These relative heights should be respected when the browser window is vertically resized. I don't want any scrolling on the page and the bottom grid shouldn't overflow out of the window. 
My html,css looks like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="panel-top">
      Master Grid
    </div>
    <div class="panel-bottom">
      Summary Grid
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

html,body{
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.header{
  position:fixed;
  border:1px solid red;
  min-height:85px;
  width:100%;
  z-index:9999;
}
.wrapper{
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  top:85px;
}
.panel-top{
  height:75%;
  background:white;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.panel-bottom{
  height:25%;
  border:1px solid blue;
  /* bottom:10px; */
}
```

I created a plunkr here- http://plnkr.co/edit/uTPpyjDe5dpuymWICT90?p=preview. Hopefully this explains my situation a bit better. I'd appreciate any help on this!!

Comment: try using flexbox http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Use the CSS3 calc() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way to do so:

1) add zero margins & paddings:

```
html,body{
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

2) replace height in wrapper:

```
.wrapper{
  position:relative;
  height:calc(100% - 85px);
  top:85px;
}
```

3) set borders to 0.